# Active Journey Builder features

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a list/resource that shows what features of JB are currently active and which are actually coming?

Comment: I'm not sure if this completely answers your question or not, but our resources on help.exacttarget.com and code.exacttarget.com will show you which Journey Builder features are available today

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/

https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/